# Three duplicates that I think should be merged (pronunciation of "coN-" words)

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I don't see any value in keeping the following three questions distinct. However, there are some valuable answers to each of them (but not too many answers). So, I think all of the answers should be merged under the most general question, with the question possibly edited to improve it.

- [The pronunciation rules of words which begin 'Com-, Col-, Cor-' or 'Con-'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269040/the-pronunciation-rules-of-words-which-begin-com-col-cor-or-con?lq=1)
- [The pronunciation of words which begins 'con' and 'com'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227247/the-pronunciation-of-words-which-begins-con-and-com?rq=1)
- [Pronunciation of 'Con' words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208182/pronunciation-of-con-words?lq=1)

Comment: The first question was hugely revised by @Araucaria http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/269040/4, he answered the third question and seeing as he has a penchant for pronunciation questions, lets give him the job!